# GCP Dataflow Template creation errors

Tags: java, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am new to dataflow and trying to create the new template from pubsub to GCS and seeing errors with SSL handshake
`https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates`

2021-12-17 00:28:42 WARN  RetryHttpRequestInitializer:111 - Request failed with IOException, performed 10 retries due to IOExceptions, performed 0 retries due to unsuccessful status codes, HTTP framework says request cannot be retried, (caller responsible for retrying): https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/******

```
[WARNING] 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataflowRunner requires gcpTempLocation, but failed to retrieve a value from PipelineOptions
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions (DataflowRunner.java:281)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod (InstanceBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build (InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions (PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create (Pipeline.java:155)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubsubToText.run (PubsubToText.java:183)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubsubToText.main (PubsubToText.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error constructing default value for gcpTempLocation: tempLocation is not a valid GCS path, gs://*******/temp. 
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create (GcpOptions.java:319)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create (GcpOptions.java:297)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:611)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:552)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getGcpTempLocation (Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions (DataflowRunner.java:279)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod (InstanceBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build (InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions (PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create (Pipeline.java:155)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubsubToText.run (PubsubToText.java:183)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubsubToText.main (PubsubToText.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to verify that GCS bucket gs://******* exists.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.verifyPathIsAccessible (GcsPathValidator.java:86)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported (GcsPathValidator.java:53)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create (GcpOptions.java:316)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create (GcpOptions.java:297)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:611)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:552)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getGcpTempLocation (Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions (DataflowRunner.java:279)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod (InstanceBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build (InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions (PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create (Pipeline.java:155)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubsubToText.run (PubsubToText.java:183)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubsubToText.main (PubsubToText.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException (Alert.java:131)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal (TransportContext.java:348)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal (TransportContext.java:291)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal (TransportContext.java:286)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts (CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate (CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume (CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume (SSLHandshake.java:377)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:422)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch (TransportContext.java:182)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode (SSLTransport.java:156)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode (SSLSocketImpl.java:1418)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord (SSLSocketImpl.java:1324)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:439)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:410)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect (HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute (NetHttpRequest.java:148)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute (NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute (HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation.retry (ResilientOperation.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.getBucket (GcsUtil.java:641)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.bucketAccessible (GcsUtil.java:629)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.bucketAccessible (GcsUtil.java:602)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.verifyPathIsAccessible (GcsPathValidator.java:83)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported (GcsPathValidator.java:53)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create (GcpOptions.java:316)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create (GcpOptions.java:297)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:611)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:552)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getGcpTempLocation (Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions (DataflowRunner.java:279)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod (InstanceBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build (InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions (PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create (Pipeline.java:155)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubsubToText.run (PubsubToText.java:183)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubsubToText.main (PubsubToText.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild (PKIXValidator.java:456)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate (PKIXValidator.java:323)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate (Validator.java:271)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:315)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts (CertificateMessage.java:638)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate (CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume (CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume (SSLHandshake.java:377)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:422)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch (TransportContext.java:182)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode (SSLTransport.java:156)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode (SSLSocketImpl.java:1418)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord (SSLSocketImpl.java:1324)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:439)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:410)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect (HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute (NetHttpRequest.java:148)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute (NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute (HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation.retry (ResilientOperation.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.getBucket (GcsUtil.java:641)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.bucketAccessible (GcsUtil.java:629)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.bucketAccessible (GcsUtil.java:602)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.verifyPathIsAccessible (GcsPathValidator.java:83)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported (GcsPathValidator.java:53)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create (GcpOptions.java:316)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create (GcpOptions.java:297)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:611)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:552)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getGcpTempLocation (Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions (DataflowRunner.java:279)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod (InstanceBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build (InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions (PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create (Pipeline.java:155)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubsubToText.run (PubsubToText.java:183)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubsubToText.main (PubsubToText.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build (SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild (SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build (CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild (PKIXValidator.java:451)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate (PKIXValidator.java:323)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate (Validator.java:271)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:315)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts (CertificateMessage.java:638)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate (CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume (CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume (SSLHandshake.java:377)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:422)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch (TransportContext.java:182)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode (SSLTransport.java:156)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode (SSLSocketImpl.java:1418)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord (SSLSocketImpl.java:1324)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:439)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:410)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect (HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute (NetHttpRequest.java:148)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute (NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute (HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation.retry (ResilientOperation.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.getBucket (GcsUtil.java:641)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.bucketAccessible (GcsUtil.java:629)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.bucketAccessible (GcsUtil.java:602)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.verifyPathIsAccessible (GcsPathValidator.java:83)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported (GcsPathValidator.java:53)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create (GcpOptions.java:316)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create (GcpOptions.java:297)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:611)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:552)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getGcpTempLocation (Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions (DataflowRunner.java:279)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod (InstanceBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build (InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions (PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create (Pipeline.java:155)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubsubToText.run (PubsubToText.java:183)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubsubToText.main (PubsubToText.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  04:16 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-17T00:28:42-08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project google-cloud-teleport-java: An exception occured while executing the Java class. DataflowRunner requires gcpTempLocation, but failed to retrieve a value from PipelineOptions: Error constructing default value for gcpTempLocation: tempLocation is not a valid GCS path, gs://pp-devcos-grc/temp1. Unable to verify that GCS bucket gs://******* exists. PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Hi - did you ever solve this?

Comment: This issue is solved. I have configured some proxies in my local machine caused this issues